# Not able to connect nokia supernova 7210 with gsmcomm library

Tags: nokia, gsm

I have connected my 7210 phone to com4. But when i run my project which uses gsmcomm library, it gives an error that no phone connected. is 7210 compatible with gsmcomm??

Answer (score 0):

GSMComm (and all similar libraries) is library, that execute AT commands for certain serial port. So question about compatibility with GSMComm library is question of compatibility with certain AT commands.

Other words, GSMComm have all methods you need to work with SMS, but your mobile phone (connected in your case to serial port COM4) can support not all AT commands which they (methods) implements. It depends on phone manufacturer, he decides which AT commands devise should to support. As I know, manufacturer can set their own set of AT commands (but I'm not sure about that).

Your trouble about "No phone connected" may be caused because of inappropriate options of baud rate and timeout. Your computer don't get any response from phone before reaching timeout. (You should look in FAQ at the homepage of GSMComm library for more details.)

I had such error message in my project. Unfortunately, I still can't resolve it, because I can't choose correct combination of baud rate and timeout for my Huawei modem.